# R forward selection forcing variables to stay in equation

Tags: r, regression

I am running a logistic regression with 755 observations and 16 variables. I am doing variable selection using glm function. glm has found the best model of 8 variables. I want these variables forced to stay in and find the next best 9 variable model using glm and step (see below).  I want to do this until I have done forward selection for models of 9-16 variables
(all 16 variables selected).

My code looks like

## SATURATED MODEL

```
full=glm(PREVAP ~ SEX + TOTCHOL + AGE + SYSBP + DIABP + as.factor(CURSMOKE)    
+ CIGPDAY + BMI + as.factor(DIABETES) + as.factor(BPMEDS) + HEARTRTE + 
  GLUCOSE + as.factor(EDUC) + TIME + HDLC + LDLC, data=training, 
  family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(full)
anova(full,test="Chisq")
full.forward <- step(null,     
scope=list(lower=null,upper=full),direction="forward", 
      family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

This gives me a model of 8 factors
I need to force these factors in next model and find a model of 9 factors using forward selection.  How to do?

I have been told bestglm and glmnet also allow for this but I do not know these packages.

Can you help?  There are a lot of options to these packages.

Sincerely,
Mary A. Marion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by seting `object` and `scope` arguments of the `step` function.

Here, using Diabetes in Pima Indian Women dataset:

```
library(MASS)
data = rbind(Pima.te, Pima.tr)
data$type = ifelse(data$type == "Yes", 1, 0)

full = glm(type~., family = "binomial", data = data)

summary(full)
anova(full, test = "Chisq")

nothing = glm(type~1, data = data, family = "binomial")

full.forward = step(nothing,
                    scope = list(lower = formula(nothing),
                                 upper = formula(full)),
                    direction = "forward")

forward = step(full.forward,
               scope = list(lower = formula(full.forward),
                            upper = formula(full)),
               direction = "forward")
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like
glm(full.forward,data=training, family=binomial(link="logit")) ?
I am getting an error.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'type' not found  I have had problems with the family=binomial logit link not being retained.

Comment: Try `glm(formula(full.forward), data=training, family=binomial(link="logit"))`